# Why doesn't stack overflow encode c++ to c%2b%2b in its URL?

Tags: url, urlencode

When I go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++ why doesn't it encode it to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b. Shouldn't that be something that the browser does? How does stack overflow prevent the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is not required to be percent-encoded when used as part of the path.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

In particular the definitions of `pchar` and `sub-delim`.